# page loading in a specific standard mode

Tags: javascript, php, css, mobile, desktop

On the android smartpone, when the mobile phone content display mode for desktop is activated, or the CSS changed?

I have a specific problem that the mobile version cannot display as a default for the user.

So, what is more changed in this exchange besides the CSS viewport?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that it is not possible to force the automatic redirection to desktop mode, because who sends the HTTP header user agent is the user, so it is something executed on the client side, even if I put the header with a certain value, it will change when the user enters the page, so only he can put it in desktop mode